# JOI - How to validade the field only with is present in Body

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I use nodejs with express and the schema Joi to validate the fields in body.

In my update route i would like validate the field only when is present in body, because i can the send  only some the fields to update, then i can't put the .required() in the schema.

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

I decided to use two schemas to the insert routes and update route and i removed the required() in schema to update route.